# Unable to get static IP for docker-compose working with macvlan driver

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've been trying to follow numerous guides on how to configure a box with a static IP with the macvlan driver, but haven't been successful. I'm using the macvlan driver because I want to bind it to a specific interface, which I don't think is possible using the bridge driver.

When pinging that address from another host, I just get timeouts. Is this expected?

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  test-box:
    image: nginx:latest
    networks:
      test-net:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.1.150

networks:
  test-net:
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: enp1s0f1.30
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.1.0/24
```

I've also tried a version 2 variant.

```
version: '2.3'

services:

  test-box:
    image: nginx:latest
    networks:
      test-net:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.1.150

networks:
  test-net:
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: enp1s0f1.30
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.1.0/24
          gateway: 192.168.1.1
          ip_range: 192.168.1.0/24
```

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS as the host system.

NOTE: This is a cut down example of the more involved docker-compose file where I want multiple boxes running, each with their own IP, all tied to a specific interface. I need to configure a static IP because external hosts will need to use one of the containers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NIC needed promiscuous mode enabled.

```
ifconfig eth1 up
ifconfig eth1 promisc
```

Answer (score -5):

`docker run -p 10.20.30.40:80:8888` will tell Docker to launch a container with port 80 on specifically IP address 10.20.30.40 routed to port 8888 in the container.  This is out-of-the-box functionality that does not require special networking configuration.  You do not need macvlan or any static IP configuration (you do need to know the host IP address of the interface you want to bind to).

Comment: That wasn't the question. This is a cut down example of the more involved docker-compose file where I want multiple boxes running, each with their own IP, all tied to a specific interface. I need to configure a static IP because external hosts will need to use one of the containers.